# Append list with dict in Django

Tags: python, django

I have this query:

```
for myid in ids_high:
    getgeom = FloodHazard.objects.get(id=myid).geom
    response_high = list(BuildingStructure.objects.filter(geom__intersects=getgeom).values(
        'brgy_locat','bldg_type','bldg_name').annotate(counthigh=Count('brgy_locat')))          
    to_json.append(response_high)
```

Which result to this:

```
[
    {
        "counthigh": 1,
        "brgy_locat": "Tolosa",
        "bldg_name": "",
        "bldg_type": ""
    },
    {
        "counthigh": 7,
        "brgy_locat": "Barangay 9",
        "bldg_name": "",
        "bldg_type": ""
    },
    {
        "counthigh": 3,
        "brgy_locat": "Mabini",
        "bldg_name": "",
        "bldg_type": ""
    }
]
```

`to_json` is a list, I wanted to a `dict` e.g. ["type":"High"]. How? I tried append and extent so far. How to append twice? is it possible?

Intended output is like this:

```
{
        "counthigh": 3,
        "brgy_locat": "Mabini",
        "bldg_name": "",
        "bldg_type": "",
        "type":"high"
}
```

and so on...

Comment: That's a list of dicts. What does "type" have to do with anything? Where is it coming from?

Comment: a fixed value..so that it will output: `"counthigh": 3,
        "brgy_locat": "Mabini",
        "bldg_name": "",
        "bldg_type": "","type":"High"`

Comment: Is 'type' a model field or is it depending on the integer counthigh? What do you want to append twice? You should probably add an example output of what you want.

Comment: no..type is not a model field, I just want to append the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to iterate over response_high and add the key `type` to each entry.

```
for myid in ids_high:
    getgeom = FloodHazard.objects.get(id=myid).geom
    response_high = list(BuildingStructure.objects.filter(geom__intersects=getgeom).values(
        'brgy_locat','bldg_type','bldg_name').annotate(counthigh=Count('brgy_locat')))          
    for entry in response_high:
         entry['type'] = 'high'
    to_json.append(response_high)
```